# Highlighted post in Django templates

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-2.1

I've created this model:

```
class PostModel(models.Model):
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    post_short_description = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    post_contents = models.TextField()
    post_publishing_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    post_author = models.ForeignKey(AuthorModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_keyconcept = models.ManyToManyField(KeyConceptModel)
    slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name="Slug", unique="True")
    post_highlighted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("singlepostManuscriptusView", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    class Meta: 
        verbose_name = "Articolo"
        verbose_name_plural = "Articoli"
```

I want use *post_highlighted* for put in a *div* only the article or the articles that have response *true*.

**How I can set up the "for cicle"?**

Here there is the cicle for show the list of posts:

```
{% for posts in object_list %}

<div id="bloghome" class="container">
  <h1><a href="{{ posts.get_absolute_url }}">{{ posts.post_title }}</a></h1>
  <p>{{ posts.post_short_description|safe|linebreaks }}</p>
  <p>Pubblicato il <strong>{{ posts.post_publishing_date|date }}</strong></p>
  <h5>Keywords:</h5>
    {% for keyword in object_list.all %}
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm">{{ keyword }}</button>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<hr>

{% empty %}

  <h1>Go to the admin panel and create your first post!</h1>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I don't know what "for cicle" means. But why wouldn't you do this in the view, by filtering the queryset by `post_highlighed=True`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do this in the template, you can change the `queryset` of the `ListView` (well based on the `object_list` I assume you use a `ListView` or at least a related class):

```
class MyPostView(ListView):

    model = PostModel
    queryset = PostModel.objects.filter(post_highlighted=True)

    # ...
```

Now the `object_list` will only contain `PostModel` objects with `post_highlighted = True`.

If you use another view where you construct the `object_list` yourself, you can write it like:

```
object_list = PostModel.objects.filter(post_highlighted=True)
```

so as long as `object_list` contains the highlighted `PostModel` objects, we are fine.

The advantage of doing this at the `queryset` level is that we will *query the database* for highlighted `PostModel` objects. We thus perform a query:

```
SELECT postmodel.*
FROM postmodel
WHERE post_highlighted = TRUE
```

Databases typically can efficiently search for such records, and furthermore we avoid doing the filtering at Django/Python-level, which is usually a magnitude slower.

Imagine if two posts out of hundred are highlighted. Then by not filtering at the database level, you transfer the data of all hundred posts to Django, do the deserialization, loop over these, and throw away the 98 non-highlighted almost instantly. This is a lot of work for nothing.

> **Note**: typically models have no `Model` suffix. I advise you to rename the model to `Post`.

Comment: If I have understanded, in this mode I can show ONLY post in which condition highlighted is True. The other types of posts aren't shown, right?
NB: Yes I've used the generic list view

Comment: Yes, if you want to show all posts, and do something "special" to highlighted ones, you can write template logic.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with simple if statement

```
{% for posts in object_list %}
  {% if posts.post_highlighted %}
    <div id="bloghome" class="container">
      <h1><a href="{{ posts.get_absolute_url }}">{{ posts.post_title }}</a></h1>
      <p>{{ posts.post_short_description|safe|linebreaks }}</p>
      <p>Pubblicato il <strong>{{ posts.post_publishing_date|date }}</strong></p>
      <h5>Keywords:</h5>
        {% for keyword in object_list.all %}
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm">{{ keyword }}</button>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <hr>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```