# Exclude a type of post from pagination

Tags: django, pagination, django-templates, django-views, django-2.1

I use a model for the posts of my blog that you can see [here(Is a my old post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52121761/highlighted-post-in-django-templates).

As you can see, in that moldel, I've an option to indicate highlighted post. If I use the code below to implement the pagination on my blog, also the highlighted post is sent in a page different from the first.

```
  {% for post in posts %}
    {% if post.highlighted == 1 %}
      <h1><strong>Highlighted</strong></h1>
      <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}"><img src="{{ post.header_image }}" alt="Image of {{ post.title }}"></a>
      <h1><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
      <h4>{{ post.tagline }}</h4>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
<hr><hr><hr>
  {% for post in posts %}
    {% if post.highlighted == 0 %}
      <h1><strong>Not Highlighted</strong></h1>
      <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}"><img src="{{ post.header_image }}" alt="Image of {{ post.title }}"></a>
      <h1><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
      <p>{{ post.tagline }}</p>
      <h5>{{ post.publishing_date|date }}</h5>
      {% for keyconcepts in post.keyconcepts.all %}
        <a href="#">#{{ keyconcepts }}</a>&nbsp;
      {% endfor %}
      <hr>
    {% endif %}

  {% endfor %}

  {% block pagination %}
    {% if is_paginated %}
      <div class="pagination px-auto">
        <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
          <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
              {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
              <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link text-center shadow" href="{{ request.path }}?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Pagina precedente</a>
              </li>
              {% endif %}
              <li class="page-item disabled">
                <p class="page-link text-center shadow">Pagina {{ page_obj.number }} di {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.</p>
              </li>
              {% if page_obj.has_next %}
              <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link text-center shadow" href="{{ request.path }}?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Pagina successiva</a>
              </li>
              {% endif %}
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    {% endif %}
  {% endblock %}
```

I would like to exclude all highlighted post from the pagination. Is it possible?

Below **views.py**

```
class ListPost(ListView):
    model = Blog
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    queryset = Blog.objects.filter(category="G.I.S.") #FUNDAMENTAL FILTER
    template_name = "blog/list_post.html"
    paginate_by = 3
```

Comment: But Willem gave you the answer to this in your original post, except you need to select is_highlighted=False.

Comment: I've adopted a different solution for the html template in relation to the my old post. I've updated the html code, sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ListPost(ListView):
    queryset = Blog.objects.filter(is_highlighted=True)
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    template_name = "blog/list_post.html"
    paginate_by = 3
```

Note `Blog` seems a misnomer. `BlogPost` seems more accurate.

Comment: You suggestion is not correct. I don't want only the highlighted post, but all posts of "GIS" category and the pagination with the highlighted post, always, on the top of the list of the posts at the first page.

Comment: you did not mention anything about `category` until you [edited it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53253571/revisions) after I answered the question :|

Comment: why not do `queryset = Blog.objects.filter(category="G.I.S.", is_highlighted=True)` ?

Comment: Because I've this: django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'is_highlighted' into field. Choices are: category, contents, draft, header_image, highlighted, id, keyconcepts, post_ptr, post_ptr_id, publishing_date, sl

ug, tagline, timeaction_ptr, timeaction_ptr_id, title, updating_date

Comment: The answer is in the error - your field name is `highlighted`, not `is_highlighted`  so it's `queryset = Blog.objects.filter(category="G.I.S.", highlighted=True)`